# Scala reading multidimensional array [Array[Array[Int]] from file

Tags: java, arrays, scala, multidimensional-array, apache-spark

I need to replicate the result from this array definition using an external file.

```
scala> val data = Seq(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)),Array(Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2)),Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)),Array(Array(6)))

data: Seq[Array[Array[Int]]] = List(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)), Array(Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2)), Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)), Array(Array(6)))
```

I tried creating a testdataI.txt file but can't make it to work.

testdataI.txt ->

```
1,2
3
1
3,2
1,2
1,2
5
6
```

Here the result when I do the conversion using `io.Source`:

```
import scala.io.Source

scala> val data = Seq(Source.fromFile("/tmp/testdataI.txt").getLines().map(_.split(",").map(_.trim.toInt)).toArray)

data: Seq[Array[Array[Int]]] = List(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3), Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(5), Array(6)))
```

The outcome should look like this (A series of Multidimensional Arrays)

```
data: Seq[Array[Array[Int]]] = List(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)), Array(Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2)), Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)), Array(Array(6)))
```

I found a lot of Multidimensional array information but nothing for this specific case.

Really appreciate,

Fredy A Gomez

Comment: First of all it looks like your input is a mixture of 2D and 1D arrays - I think that's where the confusion is starting.

Comment: I've looked at your desired output, and I can't work out the rules for what elements go in what array. Can you explain?

Comment: BTW, This is the version without using an external file. This gives me the result I want, but I need to do the same reading an external file : 

val data = Seq(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)),Array(Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2)),Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)),Array(Array(6)))

Comment: "You can setup your own rules or combinations as you want, " What are the rules, in English? I still can't see how to take your example input data and know when to start a new array..

Comment: Maybe as Lee mentioned, the Seq creates a List (1D) of multidimensional arrays (2D)  -> List[Array(Array[Int]]) 

How do my input file and/or Scala code should look like to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this version provide the rules? The elements inside <> correspond to one array.

  <(12)3>
  <1(32)(12)>
  <(12)5>
  <6>

Comment: No, it's not helped because you've not really added any more information, just repeated yourself.  How (for example) do we know that the second `1,2` should be in one Array but the third `1,2` should be in the next Array? Just re-stating the same thing doesn't help. How do we decide when to end one Array and start another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why you want to structure the values like that, but here's how you can do it:

```
scala> import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.Source

scala> val take = List(2, 3, 2, 1)
take: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 2, 1)

scala> val data = Source.fromFile("/tmp/testdataI.txt").getLines().map(_.split(",").map(_.trim.toInt).toList).toList
data: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3), List(1), List(3, 2), List(1, 2), List(1, 2), List(5), List(6))

scala> def awesomeGrouped(ungrouped: List[List[Int]], take: List[Int]): List[List[List[Int]]] = take match {
     |         case Nil => Nil
     |         case t :: ts => ungrouped.take(t) :: awesomeGrouped(ungrouped.drop(t), ts)
     |     }
awesomeGrouped: (ungrouped: List[List[Int]], take: List[Int])List[List[List[Int]]]

scala> def fixTypes(grouped: List[List[List[Int]]]) = grouped.map(_.map(_.toArray).toArray)
fixTypes: (sorted: List[List[List[Int]]])List[Array[Array[Int]]]

scala> fixTypes(awesomeGrouped(data, take))
res0: List[Array[Array[Int]]] = List(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)), Array(Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2)), Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)), Array(Array(6)))
```

The part that makes everyone uneasy is the `take` list distribution you've chosen; it seems arbitrary.

Note I added the `fixTypes` function specifically to return the exact return types you want. But arrays are not very idiomatic Scala; are you sure you need them? If not, just remove the `fixTypes` function and invocation.

Comment: The "sort" in `awesomeSort` seems mis-named as there isn't an ordering involved. `awesomeGrouped` maybe. And while this solution works, the need to specify a different `take` list depending on what exactly is in the file does indeed make me uneasy.

Comment: Thanks mlg.

This structure is required as an input for a sequential analysis algorithm called basket analysis. It requires date of purchase, items purchased and customer ID, so all these variables are organized in a structure like  this: customer X (Date 1(item A, item B), Date 2(item C)), customer Y (Date 2(item C, item A)), customer Z ....   And I need an input file because I have 15K customers.... You solution requires me to generate a new input file (take list) which provides the rules to create a new Array(New Customer).  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can't tell the difference from the file alone between a purchase of a single item on one date (like Date2(itemC) above) and another customer ID? Nasty format to have to deal with!

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul good point about the naming; updated. FredyGomez: if you consider your question answered can you please consider accepting my answer?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: agree with your analysis. I was kinda hoping that the cardinality distribution was constant 2-3-2-1 (something better modeled by a case class and a custom deserialisation mechanism), but after learning his use case it looks like my algorithm is gonna work for just his one-off example.

Comment: Mlg, @TheArchetypaPaul, I have a huge data set. The solution above runs very well until approx 20K entries. Once I pass this amount, I get StackOverflowError. Here the outcome in the shell when running for 30K entries: 

awesomeSort(data, take)

 java.lang.StackOverflowError at scala.collection.immutable.List.take(List.scala:208) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.awesomeSort(<console>:28)

Comment: Fredy: I've tried this code with a data set of 6MB, and it doesn't stack overflow, nor it should since as it is it only retrieves the first record in your data. If it should ever crash with a memory issue, it will be an OutOfMemory, because it loads the whole file on memory in one go (when mapping getLines). My code was just an example of how to structure the file the way you want; not the entire solution. Your modification must have introduced the SO. If you're sure you want to consider my answer no longer acceptable, could you at least change your question? Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Fredy: by the way, since your record has constant size (8 lines), you should be able to just `data.grouped(8) map awesomeGroup` for a complete solution, if I see this correctly. I guarantee that won't SO. It might OOM, though, at which point you want to batch or stream. You might find out, as Paul suggests, that your records perhaps don't have constant size. Good luck!